# Why does my code in React JS goes to endless loop satisfying both conditions?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import firebase from '../../config/firebaseConfig'

import SingleEventSummary from './SingleEventSummary'

import { getEvent } from "./../../store/actions/eventActions";

import "./SingleEvent.css";
const SingleEvent = props => {
 const id = props.match.params.id;

 const [eventItem, seteventItem] = useState([]);
 const [isFavourite, setIsFavourite] = useState("no");

 //getting specific event
 useEffect(() => {

  const db = firebase.firestore().collection('newEvents').doc(id)

  db.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
   seteventItem(snapshot.data())
  })
 }, [id])

 //checking if there is favourite
 useEffect(() => {
  const db = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(props.auth.uid)
   
  db.get().then(snapshot => {
    const data = snapshot.data()
    const faves = data && snapshot.data().favorites || []
   
    faves.includes(id) ? setIsFavourite("yes") : setIsFavourite("no")
  },(error) => console.error(error))
   },[isFavourite])
    

 //setting as favourites
 const favouriteClick = (uid, eid) => {
  debugger;
  let initFav = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid);
  initFav.get().then(snapshot => {
   const arrayUnion = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(eid);
   initFav.update({
    favorites: arrayUnion,
   });
   setIsFavourite("yes")
  },(error) => console.error(error))
 }

 //remove favourites
 const removeFavourite = () => {
  debugger;
  const initFavo = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(props.auth.uid);
  initFavo.get().then(snapshot => {
   if (snapshot.data().favorites) {
    if (snapshot.data().favorites.includes(id)) {
     let data = snapshot.data().favorites.filter(el => el != id )
     initFavo.update({
      favorites: data,
     });
     setIsFavourite("no")
    }
   }
  },(error) => console.error(error))
  return () => initFavo()
 }

 console.log("wtf is this shit", isFavourite)
  
 if (isFavourite == "no") {
  return (
   <main className="single-event_main">
    <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" onClick={favouriteClick(props.auth.uid, id)}>Add As Favourites!!</a>
   </main>
  );
}
  else {
  return (
   <main className="single-event_main">
    <div className="row">
     <div className="col s6">
      <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" disabled>Favourite Event!!</a>
     </div>
     <div className="col s6">
      <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" onClick={removeFavourite}>Remove From Favourites!!</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </main>
  );
 } 
};

export default SingleEvent;
```

I am trying to set the value in hook, comparing if the event id exists in the user's database(if he/she has set that event as a favourite).

```
....
const [isFavourite, setIsFavourite] = useState("no");

//checking if there is favourite
useEffect(() => {
    debugger;
    const db = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(props.auth.uid)
    db.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        debugger;
        if(snapshot.data()) {
            if (snapshot.data().favorites) {
                if (snapshot.data().favorites.includes(id)) {
                    setIsFavourite("yes")
                }
                else if(!snapshot.data().favorites.includes(id)){
                    setIsFavourite("no")
                }
            }
        }
    }, (error) => console.error(error));
    return () => db()
},[])
....
```

The issue is, react goes inside both conditions endlessly setting the hook value both yes and no. Been stuck on this hours.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated!!!

Comment: where is `id` defined or passed? i see it being used in the `includes(id)` but not in the code

Comment: You don't need the else If statement.
You can replace that with a simple else.
Since your else If is an exact opposite of your if statement

Comment: Also nothing looks wrong here. Will need to see more code. It is probably something else.

Comment: I suspect you are doing something in `setIsFavourite()`. Can you please add the code for that in the question.

Comment: @HolyMoly that is the id passed from param

 const id = props.match.params.id;

Comment: @DanielDuong yes I did that. Nothing was working so I gave it a try if there's something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now that you have shown us more code. I can say with a large degree of confidence it is because you are calling favouriteClick in the onClick of the "Add As Favourites" button.

Which is causing a weird loop.
Change

```
onClick={favouriteClick(props.auth.uid, id)
```

to

```
onClick={() => favouriteClick(props.auth.uid, id)
```

You are welcome!

Comment: WTH man!!!
Kudos!!!
This worked!! Thanks, man!!
This was so annoying for me.
Can you also please explain to me the difference and why it is working now??
@Daniel Duong

Comment: @AbhishekPokhrel You were calling favouriteClick on every render of the component. By creating an arrow function the favouriteClick doesn't get called until it is actually clicked. Function calls in a function block won't be executed until the wrapping function is run.

Answer (score 2):

jus offering a little refactor -> this is just a bit easier to read

```
useEffect(() => {
  const db = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(props.auth.uid)

  db.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    const data = snapshot.data()
    const faves = data && snapshot.data().favorites || []

    faves.includes(id) ? setIsFavourite("yes") : setIsFavourite("no")
  },(error) => console.error(error))

  return () => db()
},[])
```

I can't see why your code would be looping perhaps we need more code as the above commenter mentioned.

Comment: Hi, I added my full related code.
Thanks for the refactored code.

Answer (score 1):

you should have a stop condition for this hook, `useEffect` hook is triggered every time you render something, so you ending up changing props and rendering and then trigger `useEffect` which change props and trigger `render` lifecycle Hook.

You should have something like that

```
useEffect(() => {
  // call database
},[setFavorite]) // here goes stop condition for useEffect
```

If `setFavorite` is still `false` it won't trigger trigger again, or if `setFavorite` is false and request from db is setting it to `true` then next time if you it's trigger `useEffect` again and `setFavorite` is still `true` then `useEffect` won't execute.

For more details read officials documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating firebase in `setIsFavourite()` then you are creating a change that will be picked up by the `.onSnapshot` listener. This will force an endless loop of : condition triggers change > listens for condition > condition triggers change > ad Infinitum.

You either need to switch from `.onSnapshot` to a one-off `.get` listener or you need to add a condition to prevent changes from propagating in this case. This custom condition will be specific to your implementation, not really something we can help with unless you show use more code and help us understand what you are trying to achieve (that should be a separate question though). So I suspect the former in this case.

Comment: Hi, I have updated with full related code.
setIsFavourite is just a hook that is set based on the value received from the firebase.

Comment: Your update hasn't addressed my point. You are creating an endless loop of changes because there is nothing to stop it. You have a listener that makes a change, the change triggers the listener, which triggers the change, which triggers the listener, which triggers a change...Just stop using the real-time listener and switch to a one-off getter.

Comment: I updated the code as per your suggestions and it still doesn't work.
The irritating thing is on each render, my code autoruns both onClick events.

Comment: That's because you have set them that way.If you don't want them to run automatically then`onClick={favouriteClick(props.auth.uid, id)}` should be `onClick={() => favouriteClick(props.auth.uid, id)}`.